# How to keep tests from failing when running tests in parallel and switching iframes?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, webdriver, specflow

I'm currently mantaining a solution of tests using selenium and specflow, and I was running everything in parallel smoothly, sharing a sigle webdriver between browser(chrome) windows.

But now i had to add a couple of scenarios that involve switching between frames, and the tests started to break randomly when run in parallel due to elements or iframes not being found.

Anyone has had this problem and knows a good way to solve this?

Edit: Some code
This is in the class I use to set up my test run

```
private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
        private ChromeWebDriver chromeWebDriver;

        public TestSetup(IObjectContainer container)
        {
            this.objectContainer = container;
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            chromeWebDriver = new ChromeWebDriver();
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<ChromeWebDriver>(chromeWebDriver);
        }
```

Then in the step file I'll initialize the webdriver in the constructor

```
 private readonly IWebDriver driver;

public LoginSteps(ChromeWebDriver chromeWebDriver)
        {
            this.driver = chromeWebDriver.WebDriver;
        }
```

Comment: How are u sharing a single webdriver in parallel execution? Can u share the relevant code?

Comment: I have not seen this and I use SpecFlow as well. Without seeing the code I would ask are you using windows handles and switching back to the main window when the task is complete?

Comment: @Grasshopper I've added some code that might help, I mainly followed specflow's documentation to do this. How do you have more than one WebDriver when using specflow? 

@ Dazed no I'm not. I never needed to, and I don't see how this would help?

Comment: Maybe I read your question wrong. You mentioned iFrames so if the code has an iFrame embedded into it, you need to switch to the iFrame. Then execute your code. Once complete you switch back to the main content. This is typically why the xpath is correct but the driver never hits it because the element is in the iframe and the driver never switched to the iframe. I just wanted to make sure this was not the issue.

Comment: @Dazed exactly. thats the case and I switch Iframes using driver.SwitchTo() . when running the test one by one it works but in parallel I assume the fact that all the tests share a webdriver it's causing issues.

Comment: I don't know SpecFlow, but how the heck are you running parallel tests with single WebDriver instance? WebDriver flow is linear, if one test opened url, and then other test opened different url, first test would surely fail because elements from first page wouldn't be located anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@Dayan54 - Please take a look at the below. I run 4-6 threads in SpecFlow and I have iFrames with no issues. Maybe this will help.

Also I have seen this so I have to ask. in some iFrames, like say social media login for FaceBook or InstaGram, when you login, it closes the iFrame automatically. This will then throw an error on anything else you do because if you try and close it, you get an error since it is already closed. Switch to main content will fail because you are already there. For that I wrote the "GoToMainHandle" method.

```
 //switch to the iframe name -

 public static void SwitchToIframe(string frameName)
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFrameException)
        {
            try
            {
                Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
            }
            catch (NoSuchFrameException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not switch to IFrame");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }


   //going back to main content when completed with iframe 


    public static void SwitchToMainContent()
    {
        Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }



   //If the iframe closes automatically, you still need to get back to the main window

         public static void GoToMainHandle()
    {
        var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although it may seem like it, my problem is not in switching frames. it's the fact that all my scenarios will share the same webdriver and switching frames for 1 window will switch for all windows, that's why when running in parallel thing get messed up. I wanted to know how do you run specflow tests in paralel without sharing the same webdriver.

Comment: My concern was when I asked you if you were switching back to main window you said no you never needed to. As for running more than one webdriver, you should not need to. I have multiple solutions for several applications and they are all doing this flawlessly. The one I am looking at right now actually has a call in my BeforeScenario to close out an iframe and this is running 5 threads. You might also want to post in the specflow forum here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/specflow or adding a SpecFlow tag on this post.

Comment: I don't need to switch window. I simply switch back to default iframe. 
This is what I thing happens:

Test A and test B start in parallel:
- Test A does driver.switchTo() to frame 2
- Test B is still running and needs to find an element on frame 1
test B fails because driver is focused on frame 2